# ReferenceError: window is not defined NextJS

Tags: reactjs, typescript, next.js

I am getting error while building the app for the production. And it kept saying that
`ReferenceError: window is not defined`. I am lost to solve the problem

FullCode:

```js
const [windowSize, setWindowSize] = useState<WindowInfo>({
        width: window.innerWidth,
        height: window.innerHeight,
    });

    useEffect(() => {
        if (typeof window !== "undefined") { // error showing in this line
            function handleResize() {
                const data: WindowInfo = {
                    width: window.innerWidth,
                    height: window.innerHeight,
                }

                setWindowSize(data);
            }

            window.addEventListener("resize", handleResize);

            handleResize();

            return () => window.removeEventListener("resize", handleResize);
        }
    }, []);
```

anyone can tell me the workaround of this problem

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`window` is a browser only thing. On the NodeJS server, `window` will not be defined.

You are already handling this inside of `useEffect`, but not in `useState`. You need something like this:

```
const isBrowser = (typeof window !== "undefined");
const [windowSize, setWindowSize] = useState<WindowInfo>({
    width: isBrowser ? window.innerWidth : 0,
    height: isBrowser ? window.innerHeight : 0,
});
```

I used 0 as a default in the above, but you can use whatever is sensible for your project.